# Does a cubic graph polynomial contain the $x_1 x_2 \cdots x_M$ term?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, coloring, np-complete, satisfiability

Given a cubic graph $G$ (i.e. a graph where all nodes have degree $3$) with $N$ nodes and $M$ edges, each edge is assigned a variable $x_i$. For each node, we are given $y_i$ which is a polynomial in the three variables connected to that node. The coefficients for all the terms in the polynomials are either $0$ or $1$. Then for the graph we define the graph polynomial $F$ as the product of all the $y_i$'s. We want to determine whether the coefficient for $x_1 x_2 x_3 ... x_M$ is $0$ or $1$ (mod $2$) (once we fully expand the associated polynomial $F$).

The following figure shows an example with $N=6$ nodes and $M=9$ edges. We want to know once we fully expand $F$, whether or not the coefficient for the term $x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5 x_6 x_7 x_8 x_9$ is $1$ (mod $2$) or $0$.

[image: Example graph]

What is the best way to test that? Is there any efficient algorithm available? Or is there a (relatively) easy way to prove it is NP-hard? Any help is appreciated. Is there some recursive procedure that could be used ?

As background this problem came up in my research for identifying the subset of the SAT problems with polynomial algorithm.

Comment: @MishaLavrov you are right. Thank you. I will post a revised problem shortly.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for your comment. I have updated the problem description.

Comment: Are your polynomials [Zhegalkin polynomials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhegalkin_polynomial)? For example, is the product of $x_1x_2$ and $x_2x_3$ equal to $x_1x_2^2x_3$ or $x_1x_2x_3$? In the latter case you can find useful information on the linked page, especially in the "Method of computation" section.

Comment: Thanks BillyJoe. They’re regular. In fact x^2 could be substituted with either 0 or 1.